# Best approach to use URL name conventions for gis REST api

Tags: python, django, url-rewriting, django-rest-framework

I am building a REST api for a gis application using the Django rest framework. Currently I am using query string in URL

> http://foo.com/OnStreetBay/?name=redroute&format=json
>
> http://foo.com/OnStreetBay/?lon=-0.298611989854982&lat=51.562766714198496&format=json

Now I want to rewrite a URL as follows:

> http://foo.com/OnStreetBay/redroute/json
>
> http://foo.com/OnStreetBay/-0.298611989854982/51.562766714198496/json

So my question:

Which approach is best for GIS REST APi.